# ERROR neutron ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networking_ovn'

Tags: python, linux, logging, openstack, openstack-neutron

I want to integrate OpenStack and Ovn according to [OpenStack official tutorial for integrating ovn into OpenStack](https://docs.openstack.org/networking-ovn/latest/install/manual.html). However,
when I start neutron-server.service, the following error(from /var/log/neutron/server.log) occurs.

2023-04-22 22:04:01.116 55307 ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime [req-ef765084-f8aa-4131-b616-9df7ece0cb43 - - - - -] Error loading class by alias: stevedore.exception.NoMatches: No 'neutron.service_plugins' driver found, looking for 'networking_ovn.l3.l3_ovn.OVNL3RouterPlugin'

Here is my neutron.config:

```
[DEFAULT]

#
# From oslo.log
#

core_plugin = neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin.Ml2Plugin
service_plugins =networking_ovn.l3.l3_ovn.OVNL3RouterPlugin
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:abcdefg@controller
auth_strategy = keystone
notify_nova_on_port_status_changes = true
notify_nova_on_port_data_changes = true
```

How can l slove this problem.

Comment: Please share your neutron.config, especially the service_plugin is relevant here. But just add the current config entirely to your question and use code tags.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have shared my neutron.config.

Comment: That's interesting, I found a little different config examples here: https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/install/ovn/manual_install.html Can you try it with `core_plugin = ml2` and `service_plugins = ovn-router`? Maybe it's a documentation issue, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also found this problem later, and tried it with `core_plugin = ml2` and `service_plugins = ovn-router`. The neutron-server.service could be started normally. I also think this is a documentation problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll create a documentation bug for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the doc you found has been retired (which isn't obvious to me except the last page update from 2019). The correct guide is [this](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/install/ovn/manual_install.html).
So the correct plugin configs are:

```
core_plugin = ml2 
service_plugins = ovn-router
```